# Casting general db call responses to types in rust

Tags: rust, struct

I have a piece of code that should fetch multiple rows from different tables from a DB. I wanted to use a unified function to the fetch, but I am stuck with some issues at hand.

The oversimplified code is something like this:

```
// uses and static variables here ...
...
// Structs

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct DbResponse<T> {y types and 
    rows: Vec<T>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct UsersRow {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    registration_date: String,
    address: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct ProductsRow {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    price: String
}

fn get_users() -> Result<DbResponse<UsersRow>, ()> {
    println!("getting data from users");
    let data: DbResponse<UsersRow> = get_table_rows_data("users").unwrap();

    Ok(data)
}

fn get_products() -> Result<DbResponse<ProductsRow>, ()> {
    println!("getting data from products");
    let data: DbResponse<ProductsRow> = get_table_rows_data("products").unwrap();

    Ok(data)
}

fn get_table_rows_data(table: &str) -> Result<DbResponse<...>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        match table {
        "user" => ...;
        "prduct" => ...
    }
    // How do I use match - or something else - to assign the expected type? 
    // Also, this seems error prone, as I might make a typo, or forget something How would using enums work and help me here? 

    let data = CLIENT
        .get(format!(
            "{DTABLE_SERVER_URL}{API}v1/dtables/{}/rows/?table_name={table}",
            GENERATED_TOKEN.dtable_uuid
        ))
        .header(
            AUTHORIZATION,
            format!("Bearer {}", GENERATED_TOKEN.access_token),
        )
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .send()?
        .json::<DbResponse<DbRow>>();
                                                       // How do I cast the end result into 
    Ok(data.unwrap())                                  // the expected struct type? 
}


fn main() {
    ...
    let users: DbResponse<UsersRow> = get_users()
    let products: DbResponse<ProductsRow> = get_products()
}
```

Appreciate any ideas for a solution. What is the de-facto way of doing this in Rust? Please forgive me being a noob.

Comment: Probably look into the [`convert` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html) especially the `[Try]From`/`[Try]Into` traits.

Comment: why dont you use ORM example https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel ? looks very popular